# VLC and Win Media Player do not permit seek on MP4 files I created

Tags: video, mp4, playback

VLC and Win Media Player do not permit seek to positions within MP4 media files that I have created.  They both play the files fine, but I cannot position to the past or ahead of the current position within the file.  These files are large (~500 MB) and hold 15 minutes of audio/video.  Using MP4 Inspector, I looked at the difference between the way I created my files vs MP4 files that do allow seek (although the later files were smaller (~20 MB)).  Two main differences were:

1. Those that allowed seek had MOOV box at the end of the file.  I put the MOOV box at the beginning of the file.
2. Those that allowed seek had 2 MDAT boxes (one for audio and one for video) and no MOOF boxes.  My file is composed of many MOOF & MDAT boxes in sequence that hold ~25KB of data.

So, should I put the MOOV box at the end of the file?  Does the problem have to do with the multiple MOOF & MDAT boxes?

Comment: MOOV is best kept at front, **don't move it to the back**... MOOF means you have a **fragmented MP4** (basically multiple small MP4 files, stitched together) and thus MOOF is a like a mini-MOOV header for each MP4 piece. There should still be a main starting MOOV before it later becomes multiple MOOF. **(1)** Does the bad file have a starting MOOV? **(2)** Does something like Chrome browser allow seeking? (drag bad file into a new browser tab/window to play it). **(3)** How did you produce the file? Can you use FFmpeg as an option (to re-package the MP4 as non-MOOF version)?

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for the response.  The files that VLC and Win Media Player don't permit seek with are created by software that I wrote (Typescript).  The files start with an FTYP box , followed by a MOOV box, then the MOOF/MDAT series of boxes.  The sample files that work (BIG BUCK BUNNY clips) I downloaded from "learningcontainer.com"  had a single two MDAT boxes followed by the MOOV box at the end.  I understand the tradeoff of putting MOOV at end.  I tried using Chrome on my files and it worked!!!  Chrome took a few seconds to load the file before it would play.  But it worked!!

Comment: Can you make a short (10 seconds) test file (MP4 that is unseekable) and send it to me for checking?

Comment: My email: `valerio_charles@yahoo.com` or else show an online download link.

Comment: @VC.One - I created a 10 sec video as requested.  When I was testing it with VLC, Win Media Player, and Chrome, I made the following observations.  (1) VLC let me seek forward but not reverse, (2) Media Player no seek at all, (3) Chrome let me seek forward and reverse.  I found that this was true on the original 500 MB files as well.  I put a copy of the file on github (markwny/sample-video).

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue by not creating a fragmented video.  MOOV is still at the beginning.